# How can i make Debugging more useful & easier to track bugs on rails development console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

When i open the server 'rails s' & then refresh the browser, I get the following error.

```
Started GET "/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-27 16:38:06 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"):
```

I have one single controller & an index action. So obviously the error is coming from there. Here is the sample code from that view.

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Video Gallery</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video_gallery.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>


Here is the error ->    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
```

I know the error is coming coz the path to the file is incorrect.

How can i make the rails console tell me:-

1). From What line number in which particular  controller/ View  this error is generated?

Any gems for this?

Comment: I don't think you can, because it's a request from the client. The log will show the page that was accessed, though.

Comment: @Dave Is there any way that i could jump to my error quickly. Because, sometime it's really a pain to figure out from which particular line in the code, error is coming.

Comment: Update: When you install latest ruby with rvm , debugger automatically gets installed. 

In addition you can add gem to your gemfile 


# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'.  ---  But i still can't run this command rails server –debugger   , it gives me error, Also i need the console to point to the particular line in my code from where the error is coming..

Comment: Update:Setting
consider_all_requests_local to true causes Rails to display those developerfriendly
error screens even when the machine making the request is remote.
config.consider_all_requests_local = true

Comment: You should put those comments as an answer and accept it. Sounds pretty cool.

Comment: I can't unless i have high reputation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install latest ruby with rvm , debugger automatically gets installed. In addition you can add gem to your gemfile # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'. --- But i still can't run this command rails server –debugger , it gives me error, Also i need the console to point to the particular line in my code from where the error is coming.

Setting consider_all_requests_local to true causes Rails to display those developerfriendly error screens even when the machine making the request is remote. config.consider_all_requests_local = true – user917158 Nov 28 at 1:49

Use the rails s   screen for debugging purposes.